# Performance Counter is not working

Tags: c#, performancecounter, ranorex

Performance Counter is not working in c#. I think it is a system problem. Because, It works fine in other system. How to correct it? It shows error for below code:

Code from Ranorex Tool:

```
string prcName = "chrome";
PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private",prcName)
Report.Info("MonAlbum  memory", (counter.RawValue / 1024).ToString("#,##0")+" KB");
```

Error:

> Can not find the performance counter with the specified classname
>   'Process' countername 'Working Set - Private'

Comment: Use the `Performance Monitor` to check that the counter exists.

Comment: Security permissions problem?

Comment: The names of the counters vary between the OS versions. Also, sometimes they get corrupted, changing all the counters into numbers. As Schaliasos said, find it using perfmon. And as cad said, try running Visual Studio under administrator privileges to rule out the security problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your valuable thoughts. 
The actual problem was the registry got corrupted. because of that the code snippet wasn't working. Reinstalling OS just solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the test under an old Os version ?

As said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965225%28VS.85%29.aspx), Process /Working Set - Private is not supported under Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP.

[image]

It seems to have a solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87529/Calculate-Memory-Working-Set-Private-Programmatica), but I have never tried.